# Computation with exponential and gamma random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with law $\Gamma(n,1/\lambda)$ and $Y$ be a random variable with exponential law with parameter $\lambda$. $X$ and $Y$ are independant.

I would like to compute $P(X+Y\geq 1, X<1)$ but I do not know how to start the computation. Is there for example a formula for $P(X+Y\geq 1 | X < 1)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent
$$
P(X+Y\geq 1, X<1)=\iint_\limits{x+y\geq 1,~x<1} f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy.
$$
You don't need the conditional probabilities $P(X+Y\geq 1 | X < 1)$.

Comment: I found $\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}$, is it correct?